# apachectl configtest "Function not implemented" and Let's Encrypt auto-renew fails

Tags: centos, apache-2.4, centos7, lets-encrypt

One of my CentOS 7 servers cannot run `certbot-auto renew` because of an error while running apachectl configtest.  Here's its output:

```
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Processing /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/domain.example.com.conf
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Cert is due for renewal, auto-renewing...
Non-interactive renewal: random delay of 21 seconds
Error while running apachectl configtest.

[Fri Feb 01 18:50:51.124734 2019] [:crit] [pid 15667] (38)Function not implemented: AH00141: Could not initialize random number generator

Could not choose appropriate plugin: The apache plugin is not working; there may be problems with your existing configuration.
The error was: MisconfigurationError('Error while running apachectl configtest.\n\n[Fri Feb 01 18:50:51.124734 2019] [:crit] [pid 15667] (38)Function not implemented: AH00141: Could not initialize random number generator\n',)
Attempting to renew cert (domain.example.com) from /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/domain.example.com.conf produced an unexpected error: The apache plugin is not working; there may be problems with your existing configuration.
The error was: MisconfigurationError('Error while running apachectl configtest.\n\n[Fri Feb 01 18:50:51.124734 2019] [:crit] [pid 15667] (38)Function not implemented: AH00141: Could not initialize random number generator\n',). Skipping.
```

As it says, **apachectl configtest** gives the following error.

```
[Sat Feb 02 04:12:38.169629 2019] [:crit] [pid 21166] (38)Function not implemented: AH00141: Could not initialize random number generator
```

I use httpd(Apache) 2.4.37 installed from yum.  It is running normally, but I'm afraid that once it stopped, it may not start again due to this.

I confirmed **/dev/random** and **/dev/urandom** exist.  I googled for solutions but this problem seems to be uncommon.  Any ideas?

Comment: Try "httpd -t" command.

Comment: I got the same result "[:crit] [pid 20119] (38)Function not implemented: AH00141: Could not initialize random number generator" from "httpd -t".

Comment: Delete files from following folder and generate new SSL.
letsencrypt/renewal
letsencrypt/live
letsencrypt/archive